# IOS app integration with facebook

Tags: php, ios, facebook, web-services

I dont have any idea about IOS development, and I code the web services for IOS apps. We have been given an app that should support login with facebook and login/register of its own.
Now, implementing login/register for the app is not an issue, but I need to know two things:-

1.) How do we implement a login in the IOS app using facebook.

2.) The app should be able to show and save certain events on facebook.

How would I/we implement these two functions. Do we implement these using web side code or IOS code..
Can anyone point me in the right direction..

Thanks

PS: I got to know about facebook-connect while I was selecting the tags ;)

Answer (score 1):

Check the Facebook SDK. They have some really helpful links and tutorials. The Facebook repository from which you can get the ios SDK from is at [this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/) link. Also Facebook's developer portal is an awesome place to get [started](https://developers.facebook.com/). If you have any further questions please let me know, I **might** be able to answer them.